# Login validation not working on HTML using JSON and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am making a login form on HTML using JSON and PHP but all of the `if` statements on success are not working but the `beforeSend` and `error` is working. Can you help me check my mistakes?

I dont know know what is wrong with the function on success. The alerts are not popping up. For example `response.success == true` is supposed to pop up ' You are successfully logged in... '

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loginForm').on('submit',function(e){

        var myForm = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'connections/login.php',
            data : new FormData($(this)[0]),
            cache: false,
            contentType:false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $("div#divLoading").show();
            },
            success: function(response){
                $("div#divLoading").hide();
                console.log(response);
                if(response.success == true)
                {
                    alert(' You are successfully logged in... ')
                }

                else if( response.success == false ){
                    alert('please enter a correct email & password');
                }
                else{
                    if(response.matric){
                        alert('email is wrong');
                    }
                    if(response.password){
                        alert('password is wrong');
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('error');
                $("div#divLoading").hide();
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');

session_start();

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if (!empty($_POST['matric']))
{
$matric=$_POST['matric'];
$password=$_POST['password'];



$pass= $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE matric=:matric AND password=:password");
$pass->bindParam(':matric', $matric);
$pass->bindParam(':password', $password);
$pass->execute();
if($pass->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) > 0)
{
    $_SESSION['matric']=$matric;
    $response = array(
    'success' => true,
    'message' => 'Login successful');
}
else
{
    $response = array(
    'success' => false,
    'message' => 'Login fail');
}

}

echo json_encode($response);
echo json_encode($_POST);

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking what the actual value of response is? What's showing up when you do `console.log(response)`?

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
echo json_encode($response);
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

which is going to issue corrupted JSON. e.g. your output is going to be

```
{"success":true,"message":"Login successful"}Array
                                             ^^^^^^---corruption
```

Since your JSON is corrupted, it won't decode properly, and `response` WON'T be what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks boss. you help was meaningful. You fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```